# ClickHouse - How can I control Replica Insert behavior

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Cluster with 2 Shard, each Shard has 2-3 Replicas.

I created a ReplicatedMergeTree in each replica and insert data to them through a Distributed table with rand() sharding key.

I have internal_replication = true, after inserted 1.1M record so this is the result I got:

Shard 1 - Rep 1: 530K records

Shard 1 - Rep 2: 20K records

Shard 1 - Rep 3: 0 records

Shard 2 - Rep 1: 550K records (I run insert command on this node)

Shard 2 - Rep 2: 0 records

I ran count() query on Distributed table and got 1.08M (expected 1.1M)
seem ClickHouse only get data from one Replica of each Shard.

How can I make it get data from all Replica in each Shard and insert balance into each Replica (expectd ~200K records per Replica in Shard 1)

Comment: To get a precise answer please provide DDL of the distributed table and tables for each replica.

Comment: Something wrong with DDL or cluster config, Each replica in normal operation mode has to contain exactly the same record count.

Comment: This is very important to understand: ReplicatedMergeTree does not use `<remote_servers>`. Replication is defined by ZK path in the table Engine. Please provide `show create table your_table` and `select * from system.macros` FROM ALL SERVERS